# How to reposition an image with a linear gradient using css?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to centre an image with a linear gradient. But the image either disappears or the gradient shifts.

I've tried using `float: left;` putting the image in a `div` container in an Html file then adding a gradient but if I do that the gradient doesn't show.

```
   width:750px;

   height: 1300px;

   background: linear-gradient(to top,black,transparent 30%), url(/images/ian-dooley-iD5aVJFCXJg-unsplash-750x1300.jpg) no-repeat;
```

I hope to be able to centre or move around my image on my website while maintaining the gradient overlay.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: To be clear: you want the gradient over top of the image? And what do you mean by center the image? Centered in relation to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    #FFFFFF 0px,     /* Have one solid white area */
    #FFFFFF 255px,   /* at the top (255px high). */
    #C4C7C9 255px,   /* Then begin the gradient at 255px */
    #FFFFFF 100%     /* and end it at 100% (= body's height). */
);
```

Also see the link, this will surely help you
http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/yyvT3/